# std::string::reserve and end-of-string 0

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation, stdstring

When pre-allocating using `std::string::reserve` do I have to add *one* for the terminating `0` explicitly in order to avoid re-allocation and subsequent copying?

For example, knowing that the string `"Hello"` of length 5 will be stored in `std::string str`, do I have to call `str.reserve(6)`?

If I read the standard correctly, then I think the answer should be *yes*. For `reserve` it says

> After reserve(), capacity() is greater or equal to the argument of reserve.

and for `capacity` in turn it states

> Returns: The size of the allocated storage in the string.

I'm not to familiar with the subtleties of the formulations in the standard, though, and I wanted to confirm my suspicion.

Comment: In C++ 11, the space for the zero is implicit. In C++ pre-11 it is up to the implementation.

Comment: To be clear, that's a *yes, add one to the string length to hold*? (In C++11 I mean, who cares about pre-11 ;)

Comment: No, it is "No, the std::string implementation will automatically reserve one [or more] extra bytes to hold the zero byte to indicate the end of the string if you call `c_str()`". Of course, if you don't call `c_str()` in pre-11, then there is no guarantee that there is a zero at the end of the string at all - or that the space is not used for something else in that case. But for C++11, you are guaranteed that there is space for a zero, and that the char immediately after the actual content is zero. (Note however this is NOT part of the string, and will not count in capacity)

Comment: @Mats Petersson: Interesting, especially the pre-11 c_str-story. The wording's a bit confusing here, because when the 0 doesn't count, then I would expect the standard to write that after 'reserve(), capacity() is *strictly* greater than the argument of reserve.' Btw, the background is that, from timings in VC2013 with C++11, I got the impression that adding 1 really speeds up things. But maybe I have to dig deeper into MS's string implementation (which may not be conforming in this regards, then?).

Comment: @Mats Petersson: Okay, if I understand your comment below correctly, then the 0 doesn't count to the 'allocated storage in the string', right? That's confusing again, but I guess that's how things are :) Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 8):

C++11 does specify (or so I've read in several places, can't actually find that wording in the n3337 document?) that the `std::string` should be stored in such a way that a zero termination for a C-style string doesn't require re-allocation.

Certainly this is what happens in the GNU C++ library, in the function _S_create:

```
template<typename _CharT, typename _Traits, typename _Alloc>
  typename basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::_Rep*
  basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::_Rep::
 _S_create(size_type __capacity, size_type __old_capacity,
      const _Alloc& __alloc)
 ....
  // NB: Need an array of char_type[__capacity], plus a terminating
  // null char_type() element, plus enough for the _Rep data structure.
  // Whew. Seemingly so needy, yet so elemental.
  size_type __size = (__capacity + 1) * sizeof(_CharT) + sizeof(_Rep);
```

The `+ 1` is there to cover the terminating character.

It then goes on to "adjust" the size to make it more optimal, using a few guessed constants for `minimum allocation` and `page_size`, but it will always be AT LEAST `__size`, and always adds `1` to make room for termination.

To figure out that it "always" does this, you have to follow the code and find that calls are made to `_M_clone` whenever the string needs to be reallocated, and `_M_clone` in turn calls `_S_create`. The code is not easy to read, as it's written to follow the standard and to be efficient, not with a goal for us mere mortals to read it.

Easier to see that `c_str` doesn't allocate anything is here:

```
  const _CharT*
  c_str() const _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
  { return _M_data(); }
```

which then calls:

```
  _CharT*
  _M_data() const _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
  { return  _M_dataplus._M_p; }
```

In other words, just returns the pointer to the actual string.

Comment: Same thing for Visual C++'s implementation, it also allocates extra storage for the terminating 0.  Thanks for the analysis of the GNU C++ library.

Comment: It remains the question about the standard? Re-reading the string-section of n4296, I think it all boils down to the meaning of capacity(). And I think the formal definition ("allocated storage") is misleading here, because the usage of capacity() in other parts plus the meaning of size() on container-level make it clear that the allocated storage for *user* data (i.e., without the terminating 0) is what it intends to say. Do you agree? or do you have an explicit statement in this direction?

Comment: The standard also states that `c_str()` should happen in constant time - in other words, it has to take the same amount of time to do `c_str()` regardless of the string inside being 1 or 1 million characters long - which implies [although it technically doesn't state it] that there should be no copy operation inside `c_str`. And clearly, the function of `capacity()` is to indiciate how much storage the user has, not the number of bytes that the internal representation takes up.

Comment: That `c_str()` cannot trigger a copying is clear from its complexity, of course, but not for assignment. I'm just not too familiar with the language in the standard, so thanks for your clarification. On the other hand a general requirement in the standard like "there must be no allocation if capacity() is large enough" would be nice; if I got it right, a (really bad) standard-conforming implementation might at the moment re-allocate even if it has enough space.

Comment: Standards documents are often vague for the purpose of "allowing alternative implementations". If you dictate too much in the standard document, it means that some optimisations or hardware restricted solutions can't be used, and that would in turn restrict the usefulness of the language - as specifications goes, the C++ spec is actually not all that bad.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> Returns: The size of the allocated storage in the string.
> ```

*Allocated storage in the string*  that statement mean that string should fit in allocated space. "String"  mean "zero-terminated group of char", so zero also should be included.

Comment: That's what `capacity()` returns yes, but what number must be passed to `reserve` to avoid an allocation when holding `"HELLO"`?

Comment: I read it more like that it's the space the string object really allocated (probably only the part on the heap, though). Which of course would have to include the terminating 0 to provide the old-school `std::string::c_str`.

Comment: The zero added for `c_str` is NOT part of the actual string stored - but, like I said above, in C++11, there will be space for it, and it is guaranteed to "be there" [obviously accessing the string in a second thread during updates in the first thread, you it is NOT guaranteed that the string is terminated at all times - you need locks in the string functions to guarantee that - and std::string doesn't have such things]

Comment: According to http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4416.pdf _After reserve(), capacity()_  **is greater** or equal to the argument of reserve. So it is enought to give 5 in case "hello" word.

Comment: @Tomasz Pluta: Of course the implementation may choose to actually make the capacity greater; but it *is* allowed to have it equal. And in the latter case, depending on what counts into the allocated space (see above), it may necessitate to a re-allocation in order to get the 0 stored somewhere; "Hello" already takes up all the pre-allocated 5 char storage.